# Run periodically and asynchronously a function that is thread unsafe in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have an IP Camera that ships with it's own library.
It's methods are all synchronous and they look like this.

This is so that there are no race conditions, i.e. I cannot call GetImage() while Configure() is running.
Note that a few of these methods take a few seconds to complete.

```
public interface ICamera
{
    bool Configure(object args); // Takes a long time
    Image GetImage(); // Takes a little time but must not be accessed by other thread.
}
```

Now, I want to wrap this library in a service class that will launch an event when a new frame is ready.
The subscriber of the event will take care of updating the ui.

I want to do something like (pseudo c#)

```
public class ICameraService
{
    public event EventHandler NewFrameAvailable;
    public event EventHandler StateChanged;
    
    private ICamera camera;
    private Timer frameTimer;

    public Configure() {
         StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Configuring"));

         // No other camera methods must be called while this is running
         // I could maybe use lock(camera)?
         camera.Configure(...);
         StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));
    }
    
    public void StartCapture() {
       frameTimer.Tick += () => {
           var image = camera.Capture();
           image = DoSomeBasicProcessing(image);
           NewFrameAvailable?.Invoke(this, NewFrameAvailableEventArgs(image));
       };

       // Sets the timer interval to 25 fps.
       frameTimer.Interval = 1.0 / 25.0;

       StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Capturing"));
       frameTimer.Start();
    }

    public void StopCapture() {
       frameTimer.Stop();
       StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that regardless of the calling thread, all the ICamera's methods run sequentially on a single background thread?

Am I on the right track? I can't understand if I should use tasks, lock every camera access (but locking an object for each frame seems very expensive).
What is the most pragmatic way to solve this I believe not so uncommon problem?

Also I have these questions:

On which thread Tick is running the lambda on (is it on the caller's thread? Is it on a different thread for each call? I would want it in one single thread.)

I want to understand how to structure the ICameraService so that all the thread unsafe code doesn't have race conditions, but still provide an asynchronous interface (either with events or async/await) to the ViewModel that will call the CameraService.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, you want to run the `camera.Configure()` and the `camera.Capture()` sequential on a background thread? Define "All the methods"

Comment: Correct, I'll edit to make it more clear

Comment: And the main problem is, how do you execute the `Configure()` ones before the `camera.Capture()` is called every `Tick` (and not blocking the calling thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a thread which initializes the camera and runs the capture periodically, until you call Stop camera. Dont forget, NewFrameAvailable runs on the capturing thread, so either create a copy or you could calculate the WaitOne(timeout) on how long the processing took.

You could do something like this:

```
public class ICameraService
{
    public event EventHandler NewFrameAvailable;
    public event EventHandler StateChanged;
    
    private ICamera camera;
    private Timer frameTimer;
    private ManualResetEvent _terminate = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private int interval;

    private Thread thread;

    public void StartCapture(int interval)
    {
        _terminate.Reset();
        this.interval = interval;
        thread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
    }

    public void ThreadMethod()
    {
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Configuring"));
        camera.Configure(...);
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Capturing"));
        while(!_terminate.WaitOne(interval))
        {
            var image = camera.Capture();
            image = DoSomeBasicProcessing(image);
            NewFrameAvailable?.Invoke(this, NewFrameAvailableEventArgs(image));
        }
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));
    }

    public void StopCapture() 
    {
       _terminate.Set();
       thread.Join();
       StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, getting closer to the solution. Is there a way to have a timer ticking rather than a while(true) loop? Or maybe I could just do a ThreadSleep() at the end of the while.

Comment: Thats the whole trick of the _terminate event. It will block the current thread (like a sleep) but when the `_terminate.Set();` is set, it will return true directly, with that it will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Timer class has a feature that will provide periodic events with locking on a specific object. See [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject?view=netstandard-2.0#examples).

It is syntactic sugar for using your own locks with the thread pool. It will not guarantee that the each interval event is run on the same thread, but it will guarantee that each event is handled one at a time.

If you want finer control or a guarantee of running on a single thread I would [create a thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/creating-threads-and-passing-data-at-start-time#creating-a-thread) and [use a Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed?view=net-5.0#examples) to determine how much time elapsed for setting your next thread timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant on the same theme, using TPL classes instead of threading primitives:

```
public class CameraService
{
    public event EventHandler NewFrameAvailable;
    public event EventHandler StateChanged;

    private ICamera _camera;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private Task _task;

    public void StartCapture(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new StateChangedEventArgs("Configuring"));
            _camera.Configure(/* ... */);
            StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new StateChangedEventArgs("Capturing"));
            while (true)
            {
                var delayTask = Task.Delay(interval, _cts.Token);
                var image = _camera.Capture();
                image = DoSomeBasicProcessing(image);
                NewFrameAvailable?.Invoke(this, new NewFrameEventArgs(image));
                try { delayTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) { break; }
            }
            StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));
        }, _cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public void StopCapture()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        try { _task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Ignore
        _cts.Dispose();
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));
    }
}
```

In case you want the events of the `CameraService` class to be raised (optionally) on the UI thread, you could consider imitating the [`SynchronizingObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) property of the `System.Timers.Timer` class. You could study the source code of this class [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs.html#dc67c9466604a3d9), to see how this property is used.

Comment: I like your solution using Tasks, but I believe that the `StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new StateChangedEventArgs("Idle"));` line after the `while(true) {}` is never called.

Comment: @AFusco yeap, you are right. I put the try/catch at the wrong place. It should be OK now.